# Displaying image from parse on Picker upload

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, uiimagepickercontroller, pfobject

Thanks to the help of @stee i was able to get the image to upload to the right class in parse.com. Now i can't get it to display that same image in the same uiimageview i used to upload .

with the help of @stee and @Joey i was able to add the code below to my viewdidload. Now i get a warning saying unused variable for the *image and when i compile and run  i can upload but as soon as i leave that controller, the image won't be there.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFFile * myPFFile = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"ProfilePicture"];
[myPFFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        // image can now be set on a UIImageView
    }
}];
}
```

if it helps you understand what I've done, below is the code i used to upload the photo

```
PFObject *User = [PFUser currentUser];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 0.8);
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", _username.text];
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
[User setObject:imageFile forKey:@"ProfilePicture"];
```

is there anything that I'm missing from my viewdidload? am i missing anything from my .h file?

in my .h file i have that uiimageview like;

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

i would greatly appreciate any further help in making this possible.

Comment: @Stee any idea what i could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After you have saved the image to the user on upload it is then accessible as a PFFile via [User objectForKey:@"ProfilePicture"];
You would then set the image on the image view using one of the PFFile loadInBackground functions.

I have spotted a problem elsewhere in your code as well, the user which you are saving the image to is a new PFUser every time. Replace [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"User"]; with [PFUser currentUser];

Comment: Tnx for the catch. I noticed i had created a new class and uploaded the file millions of times as opposed to adding it to the current user. Im still trying to figure out how to show the image now after its been added.

Comment: Joey Clover's answer shows you the code to get the image from the file object. You just need to get the PFFile from the current user in viewDidLoad using  PFFile * myPFFile = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"ProfilePicture"]; then use the code from his answer and set the image on the image view.

Answer (score 0):

You could either save the image that was selected to disk or request the Users profile from Parse every time you "viewDidLoad" in your controller.

Saving the image to disk using `[_imageView.image writeToFile:myFilePath atomically:YES];` saves you making network requests but if the user can change the picture using methods other than the app, it's probably not the best choice.

With respect to requesting the image each time, you can do a "fetch" on the `[PFUser currentUser]`. Once you do the fetch, you can get the `PFFile *file` from `[PFUser currentUser]["ProfilePicture"]`. Once you've got the PFFile from your PFUser, you can then proceed to convert it:

```
[myPFFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    // image can now be set on a UIImageView    
  }
}];
```

That's about the best way I can explain it with the information you've given me!